# Facebook, WordPress and log in

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a problem with my site made in [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) and I made a custom Facebook login using the Facebook [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) and in another page I use the Facebook [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) SDK. But when I log-in in WordPress using its standard login (and not with the Facebook login) and when I went to the page where I use the JavaScript SDK to post on my wall, and if someone is logged in to this computer with another account it connects to that account, so my solution is to first logout all the Facebook connections and when I go to that page I'll just login again using the JavaScript SDK. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the Facebook session for that.

Whenever you are creating object of Facebook, it will check for the sesison of Facebook.
In WordPress login it will show the WordPress user login details, but when you are accessing the page which has Facebook SDK code it, it will consider the user is already logged in with Facebook.

You can make a condition on the basis of your requirement. For destroying the session, use the logout function of the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) or whatever SDK you are using then it will ask you for login with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that login using the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) and the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) SDK is in a different session.

I do have a application that integrate with both PHP and JavaScript login. I found that the user have to login both instead of login using JavaScript or PHP only.

You can have a look at `www.wootube.woolei.com`.

Answer (score 0):

you can login with anyone sdk you have to check only for the session that session is there or not so you can come to know that user is logged in with facebook or not. Whenever there will be a problem then you can take session value in a seperate session so you can use that whereever you want.